# Separate a string of multiple dates and names in R

Tags: r, string

I have a dataframe with 2 columns, where the first column lists companies and the second column are strings of multiple dates and company names as follows:

```
data=data.frame('Company'=(c("A","B","C")),
                'Bank'=c("1/13/2020 Bank A 5/12/2020 Bank H C 11/9/2020 HelloBank",
                         "2/14/2020 HopeBank 1/9/2020 Liberty Bank SA",
                         "10/18/2020 Securities"))
```

I would like to separate column "Bank" into multiple columns of Dates and Bank Names, such that:

```
data=data.frame('Company'=(c("A","B","C")),
                "Date1"=(c("1/13/2020","2/14/2020","10/18/2020")),
                'Bank1'=c("Bank A", "HopeBank","Securities"),
                "Date2"=(c("5/12/2020","1/9/2020",NA)),
                'Bank2'=c("Bank H C", "Liberty Bank SA",NA),
                "Date3"=(c("11/9/2020 ",NA,NA)),
                'Bank3'=c("HelloBank", NA,NA))
```

I have tried using library(stringr) but the formats of the dates are not consistent. Also, I do not know how many variables I will need in the final dataframe, and some of the strings in the "Bank" column are very long (up to 824 nchar).

I have also tried using separate from tidyr but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R option using `strsplit` to make it

```
v <- strsplit(data$Bank, "\\s(?=(\\d+\\/))|(?<=\\d)\\s", perl = TRUE)
data <- cbind(
  data[1],
  `colnames<-`(
    do.call(rbind, lapply(v, `length<-`, max(lengths(v)))),
    paste0(c("Date", "Bank"), rep(1:(max(lengths(v)) / 2), each = 2))
  )
)
```

which gives

```
> data
  Company      Date1      Bank1     Date2           Bank2     Date3     Bank3
1       A  1/13/2020     Bank A 5/12/2020        Bank H C 11/9/2020 HelloBank
2       B  2/14/2020   HopeBank  1/9/2020 Liberty Bank SA      <NA>      <NA>
3       C 10/18/2020 Securities      <NA>            <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how many banks there might be in each row, you are better off creating a dataframe in long format.  Something like this will do it, using the `tidyverse`...

```
library(tidyverse)

data_long <- data %>% 
  mutate(Bank = str_replace_all(Bank, "( \\d+/)", "#\\1"),  #add markers between banks
         Bank = str_split(Bank, "#")) %>%                   #split at markers
  unnest(Bank) %>%                                          #convert to one row per entry
  mutate(Bank = str_squish(Bank)) %>%                       #trim white space
  separate(Bank, into = c("Date", "BankName"), sep = " ", extra = "merge")

data_long

  Company Date       BankName       
  <chr>   <chr>      <chr>          
1 A       1/13/2020  Bank A         
2 A       5/12/2020  Bank H C       
3 A       11/9/2020  HelloBank      
4 B       2/14/2020  HopeBank       
5 B       1/9/2020   Liberty Bank SA
6 C       10/18/2020 Securities
```

You might then want to convert `Date` into date format.

If you really want it in wide format, use `pivot_wider`.

Comment: You got there before me. `anytime::anydate()` will convert all the dates in the same format